# Why is getElementByID null?

Tags: javascript, php, css, getelementbyid, dropdown

I was trying to design a dropdown menu (though, admittedly, they aren't quite going as planned.)

My main issue is, despite not being able to spot any syntax errors, I seem to be getting something in `getElementByID` as null, hence nothing is really showing up except the content of body.

Is it because I was kinda lazy and used the same class name for both dropdowns (the ID is different and I checked to make sure the spelling was the same for both the ID and the `getElementByID`), so I shouldn't be messing with the same dropdown.

True, in the CSS, I don't quite have the elements for `eAndADropdown` fully styled yet, but that shouldn't cause this error, should it?

Right now, everything is vanishing.  Normally, I'd think it was a syntax error, but, if it is one, it totally eludes me as I've checked and checked.

I even checked the `&` in the Events and Activities, having both a `;` after the `&` code and also no `;` after the `&` code, just to see if that was it.  Seems to make no difference:

```
<?php
echo "<div id='content'>";
echo "<div id='logo'>";
echo "<img src='./logo.png'></img>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='container'>";
echo "<nav id='hor'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a> </li>";
echo "<li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' onclick='showEAndADropdownHor()'> Events &amp Activities &darr;</a>";
echo "<div class='dropdown-content' id='eAndADropdown'>";
   echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Main </a></li>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<li> <a href='./foggyGoggle.php'> Foggy Goggle </a></li>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./lessons.php'>  Ski Lessons </a></li>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
?>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function showEAndADropdownHor() {
    document.getElementById("eAndADropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<?php

</li>";
echo "<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us </a></li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'> <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' onclick='showRestaurantDropdownHor()'> Restaurants &darr;</a>";
echo "<div class='dropdown-content' id='restaurantDropdown'>";
         echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li><a href='./grandviewbistro.php'>Grand View Bistro</a></li>";
    echo "<br/>";
      echo "<li><a href='./angelescrestcafe.php'>Angeles Crest Caf&eacute</a></li>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo " <li><a href='./goldrushgrill.php'>Goldrush Grill</a></li>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./bullwheelbarandgrill.php'>  Bullwheel Bar &amp  Grill </a></li>";
      echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./bigpinesbarbecue.php'> Big Pines Barbecue </a></li>";
   echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./northpolegrill.php'> North Pole Grill </a></li>";
     echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
?>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function showRestaurantDropdownHor() {
    document.getElementById("restaurantDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<?php

echo"</li>";
echo "<li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</nav>";
echo "<div id='middle'>";
echo "<nav id='vert'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a></li> <br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li><br/>";
echo"<li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Events &amp Activities </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us</a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./restaurants.php'> Restaurants  &rarr; </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li><br/>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</nav>";
?>
```

What could be the problem?

I also found that the following code does work:

```
<?php



echo "<div id='content'>";
echo "<div id='logo'>";
echo "<img src='./logo.png'></img>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='container'>";
echo "<nav id='hor'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a> </li>";
echo "<li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Events &amp Activities 

</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us </a></li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'> <a href='javascript:void(0)' 

class='dropbtn' onclick='showRestaurantDropdownHor()'> 

Restaurants &darr;</a>";
echo "<div class='dropdown-content' id='restaurantDropdown'>";
         echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li><a href='./grandviewbistro.php'>Grand View 

Bistro</a></li>";
    echo "<br/>";
      echo "<li><a href='./angelescrestcafe.php'>Angeles Crest 

Caf&eacute</a></li>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo " <li><a href='./goldrushgrill.php'>Goldrush Grill</a></li>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./bullwheelbarandgrill.php'>  Bullwheel Bar 

&amp  Grill </a></li>";
      echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./bigpinesbarbecue.php'> Big Pines Barbecue 

</a></li>";
   echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./northpolegrill.php'> North Pole Grill 

</a></li>";
     echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
?>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function showRestaurantDropdownHor() {
    document.getElementById("restaurantDropdown").classList.toggle

("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName

("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<?php

echo"</li>";
echo "<li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</nav>";
echo "<div id='middle'>";
echo "<nav id='vert'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a></li> <br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li><br/>";
echo"<li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports 

</a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Events &amp Activities 

</a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us</a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./restaurants.php'> Restaurants  &rarr; 

</a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li><br/>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</nav>";



?>
```

Also, on the offchance that it's something in my css, I'll post that too:

```
#logo
{

border: 1px dashed purple;
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}

#logo > img
{
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}


.floatleft
{
float: left;

}


.floatright
{
float: right;

}

#content
{

 border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;


width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 800;



}


nav
{


      border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;
  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 112%;

}

nav#vert
{

 width: 220px;
  height: 540px;
  margin: 0px;
  display:table-cell;

}

body { 
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #422520;
  background-image: url(./snow_mountain.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;

   background-size:cover;
  text-align: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

#footerContainer
{

 border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;

}

footer
{

    border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;


  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;

  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;

}


footer > a
{
color: white;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;

}

#container
{
  border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1050px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 750px;

}


nav > a
{

color: #ccccff;

}

nav#hor > div
{

border: 1px solid white;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000044;
}

nav#hor
{
width: 1000px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 112%;

}


nav#hor a
{

color: rgb(0 0,238);
}


nav#hor > div >  a
{

color:  #ccccff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100%;
}



nav#hor>div:hover
{

background-color: #018802;

}

h1
{
font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;

font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 36px;

}

h2
{

font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 26px;
}

h3
{

font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}




#text-container
{





border: 2px solid cyan;



   width: 1005px;
  height: 690px;
  */ zoom: 1;
  */ margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;

 padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;


}

#text-container:after
{
clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility:hidden;

}

#text-container > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

.left img
{

float: left; 
padding: 0 20px 20px 0;

}





.left > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}


.right img
{
float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;

}



.right > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}


nav#hor ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000044;

}

nav#hor ul li:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;

}

nav#vert ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000044;

}
nav#hor li
{
float: left;
border: 1px solid white;.

}

nav#vert li
{
float: left;
border: 1px solid white;.

}


nav#vert  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
  //  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


 nav#hor  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
  //  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


nav#hor   li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #018802;
}

nav#vert   li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #018802;
}


 li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
}

#eAndADropdown
{


}

#restaurantDropdown li
{
background-color: #000044;
border: 1px solid white;

}

#restaurantDropdown  ul
{
border: 1px solid white;

}



#restaurantDropdown:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;
}

#restaurantDropdown a
{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
     border: 1 px solid white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

li  a
{

color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
}
```

Comment: The dynamic generation with PHP is probably the culprit, `getElementById()` isn't finding elements with IDs specified because they don't exist when using the function

Comment: I don't get it, it worked when I did it with just the restaurant one.  What is going wrong when I tried to duplicate what I did with the restaurant one in order to create an Events & Activities drop down.

Comment: Not a PHP guy, sorry

Comment: It probably isn't even a PHP error.   I'm thinking it's a JS error somewhere.

Comment: The PHP isn't doing anything dynamic. It's just printing HTML strings, which btw isn't necessary. You're better off just leaving it outside of `<?php ?>` as just plain HTML, like you did with your `<script>` tags.

Comment: i don't think its a php issue, php gets rendered THEN It sends the HTML rendered to the browser requesting.  At that point, the browser executes the javascript which means PHP is completely out of the equation.

Comment: This is actually an include file.   It's being included in all my other files.   Problem is, whatever is causing it to go wrong is breaking every file.

Comment: There was a similar issue with dropdown.js which presented that error in Firefox, a solution was removing href="#" from the anchor, maybe href='javascript:void(0)' is what is causing your error.

Comment: Why you did not select an answer?

Answer (score 2):

1.Yoy have php error. Line `</li>";` should be like this  `echo "</li>";`

2.All your `href='javascript:void(0)'` replace with href='#'

3.Add css style

```
  <style>
        .dropdown-content{
            display: none
        }
        .dropdown-content.show{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
```

**Full html output**

```html
<div id='content'>
  <div id='logo'><img src='./logo.png'></img>
  </div>
  <div id='container'>
    <nav id='hor'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a> </li>
        <li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li>
        <li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li>
        <li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li>
        <li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropbtn' onclick='showEAndADropdownHor()'> Events &amp Activities &darr;</a>
          <div class='dropdown-content' id='eAndADropdown'>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Main </a></li>
              <br/>
              <li> <a href='./foggyGoggle.php'> Foggy Goggle </a></li>
              <br/>
              <li><a href='./lessons.php'>  Ski Lessons </a></li>
              <br/>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <script>
            /* When the user clicks on the button,
            toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
            function showEAndADropdownHor() {
              document.getElementById("eAndADropdown").classList.toggle("show");
            }

            // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
            window.onclick = function(e) {
              if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
                  var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
                  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                  }
                }
              }
            }

          </script>
          <style>
            .dropdown-content {
              display: none
            }
            
            .dropdown-content.show {
              display: block;
            }

          </style>
        </li>
        <li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li>
        <li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li>
        <li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us </a></li>
        <li class='dropdown'> <a href='#' class='dropbtn' onclick='showRestaurantDropdownHor()'> Restaurants &darr;</a>
          <div class='dropdown-content' id='restaurantDropdown'>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='./grandviewbistro.php'>Grand View Bistro</a></li>
              <br/>
              <li><a href='./angelescrestcafe.php'>Angeles Crest Caf&eacute</a></li>
              <br/>
              <li><a href='./goldrushgrill.php'>Goldrush Grill</a></li>
              <br/>
              <li><a href='./bullwheelbarandgrill.php'>  Bullwheel Bar &amp  Grill </a></li>
              <br/>
              <li><a href='./bigpinesbarbecue.php'> Big Pines Barbecue </a></li>
              <br/>
              <li><a href='./northpolegrill.php'> North Pole Grill </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <script>
            /* When the user clicks on the button,
            toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
            function showRestaurantDropdownHor() {
              console.log('showRestaurantDropdownHor');
              console.log(document.getElementById("restaurantDropdown"));
              document.getElementById("restaurantDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
            }

            // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
            window.onclick = function(e) {
              if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
                  var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
                  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                  }
                }
              }
            }

          </script>
        </li>
        <li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id='middle'>
      <nav id='vert'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Events &amp Activities </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us</a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./restaurants.php'> Restaurants  &rarr; </a></li>
          <br/>
          <li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li>
          <br/>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

**your fixed code**

```
<?php
echo "<div id='content'>";
echo "<div id='logo'>";
echo "<img src='./logo.png'></img>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='container'>";
echo "<nav id='hor'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a> </li>";
echo "<li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropbtn' onclick='showEAndADropdownHor()'> Events &amp Activities &darr;</a>";
echo "<div class='dropdown-content' id='eAndADropdown'>";
   echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Main </a></li>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<li> <a href='./foggyGoggle.php'> Foggy Goggle </a></li>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./lessons.php'>  Ski Lessons </a></li>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
?>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function showEAndADropdownHor() {
    document.getElementById("eAndADropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
    .dropdown-content{
        display: none
    }
    .dropdown-content.show{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<?php

echo "</li>";
echo "<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us </a></li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'> <a href='#' class='dropbtn' onclick='showRestaurantDropdownHor()'> Restaurants &darr;</a>";
echo "<div class='dropdown-content' id='restaurantDropdown'>";
         echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li><a href='./grandviewbistro.php'>Grand View Bistro</a></li>";
    echo "<br/>";
      echo "<li><a href='./angelescrestcafe.php'>Angeles Crest Caf&eacute</a></li>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo " <li><a href='./goldrushgrill.php'>Goldrush Grill</a></li>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./bullwheelbarandgrill.php'>  Bullwheel Bar &amp  Grill </a></li>";
      echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./bigpinesbarbecue.php'> Big Pines Barbecue </a></li>";
   echo "<br/>";
     echo "<li><a href='./northpolegrill.php'> North Pole Grill </a></li>";
     echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
?>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function showRestaurantDropdownHor() {
    console.log('showRestaurantDropdownHor');
    console.log(document.getElementById("restaurantDropdown"));
    document.getElementById("restaurantDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<?php

echo"</li>";
echo "<li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</nav>";
echo "<div id='middle'>";
echo "<nav id='vert'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a></li> <br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li><br/>";
echo"<li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Events &amp Activities </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us</a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./restaurants.php'> Restaurants  &rarr; </a></li><br/>";
echo "<li><a href='./about.php'> About </a> </li><br/>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</nav>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I bet that was it.

Comment: What's the reason for #2? What's wrong with `href="javascript:void(0)`?